# Csharp component which generates fragments with highlights for diffs for 2 strings

Tags: c#, diff, highlighting

I need C# implementation ( ideally open source )  which is similar to Delphi DLL.
I am currently using the wrapper ( C# syntax is provided , but it is a call from a different language )

```
zdiff( string ref str1, string ref str2, int range , int trim  )
```

it calls inside

```
str1 = GetHiDiff(@str1,1,trim)
str2 = GetHiDiff(@str1,2,trim)
```

where

```
function GetHiDiff(s:pchar; sIndex:integer; wtrim:integer): pchar; stdcall;
```

What it does it returns a left fragment html of str1 and a right html fragment of str2  with diffs highlighted as strings are passed by reference. Range parameter determines the size of html fragment. Not sure what trim > 0 does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. DiffPlex - a .NET Diff Generator

http://diffplex.codeplex.com/